# Firebase verify email issue when using sendEmailVerification method in AngularFire2

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angular6, angularfire2

**Tech Stack:**

Currently using angular6, firebase, angularfire2 and angularcli6.

**Attempt / Issue:**

Currently on signup I call Firebase sendEmailVerification.

This sends the user an email to verify their account.

They click the link and it send the user to account-management page on my website.

I then need to update the field emailVerified to true but it wont let me since its a readonly field.

> How can I update the currentUser with emailVerified set to true, as Firebase doesn't seem to do it automatically for me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you send email verification link to user, the link is very similar to following

http://localhost:4200/new-password?mode=verifyEmail&oobCode=OOBCODEHERE&apiKey=APIKEYHERE&lang=en

When the user clicks the link, it redirects you to the new-password route of your domain (localhost:4200 here).

You can change the route and component at firebase authentication>Templates>Email address verification templates changing the url sent to user email address.

You need to implement your email verification logic with checkActionCode and applyActionCode method yourself using oobCode provided in url.

I have implemented this as below

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-new-password',
  templateUrl: './new-password.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./new-password.component.css']
})
export class NewPasswordComponent implements OnInit {
 emailVerificationCode:string;
 apiKey:string;
  constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) { 
   this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
        this.emailVerificationCode = params['oobCode'];
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
   firebase.auth().checkActionCode(this.emailVerificationCode).then(
    (user)=>{
     console.log("User Info KKKKK : " + user.data.email);
     firebase.auth().applyActionCode(this.emailVerificationCode).then(
      ()=>{
       let ref=firebase.database().ref('verifiedEmails/'+user.data.email.replace('.','*'));
       ref.set(true).then(
        ()=>{
         console.log("Email Verfied");
        }
     ).catch(
      (error)=>{
       console.log("Couldn't set true : " + error.message);
      }
     )
      }
   ).catch(
    (error)=>{
     console.log("Error occured : " + error.message);
    }
   )
    }
 )
  }
  }
```

Reference: Alex from
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/EGYwg2vjRq4

Comment: Thank you, I will try this shortly

Comment: @Prakash Khadka one question. Why you use: let ref=firebase.database().ref('verifiedEmails/'+user.data.email.replace('.','*'));

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `user.reload()` API to do that. Check the doc here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#reload

Comment: Thanks I will try shortly

Comment: I tried that, the emailVerified field is still false. How do I make it true? because clicking the verify link in the email didnt work?